# What is the use of providing browser version in HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

I am trying to run selenium webdriver in Linux machine. So i tried to use HtmlUnitDriver to achieve this.

I am getting the following error while executing the jquery.

```
TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object HTMLDocument]. (http://localhost/xxx/js_lib/jquery2/jquery-2.1.0.min.js#2)
```

The above exception is occured when the HtmlunitDriver is used without any browser version as below,

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

Also the junit test case is getting failed with following reason,

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with ID: abcde
```

If i pass the Browser version as below,

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

The test case is getting pass, but exception is thrown in the console like,

```
SEVERE: Job run failed with unexpected RuntimeException: Exception invoking Window.getComputedStyle() with arguments [Text, String]
======= EXCEPTION START ========
Exception class=[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking Window.getComputedStyle() with arguments [Text, String]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:847)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:779)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest.setState(XMLHttpRequest.java:233)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest.doSend(XMLHttpRequest.java:762)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest.access$000(XMLHttpRequest.java:104)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest$1.run(XMLHttpRequest.java:623)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavascriptXMLHttpRequestJob.run(JavascriptXMLHttpRequestJob.java:36)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.runSingleJob(JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.java:415)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.run(DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.java:167)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exception invoking Window.getComputedStyle() with arguments [Text, String]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:193)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:449)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1536)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3286)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:772)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:832)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@4d3015e7
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:153)
    ... 22 more
```

I have the following list of questions,

1. To use firefox browser in HtmlUnitDriver, Do i need to install firefox in Linux machine ?
2. why the above exceptions are thrown?
3. Is there any option to run selenium in lunix machine without GUI?

I am starter in selenium and need your valuable thoughts on this. thanks

Comment: Hi.. Any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 0):

> To use firefox browser in HtmlUnitDriver, Do i need to install firefox in Linux machine ?

No, you don't need to install any real browsers.

> Why the above exceptions are thrown?

Because HtmlUnit JavaScript support is not very accurate sometimes, please read [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html).

Also, please try to provide complete details (URL or small sample project), so others can see the same errors.